# passing argument 1 of 'swap' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I am really new with programing and don't know where the errors are...

When I try to compile it, it just gives a segmentation fault,

Can someone help me please?

```
size_t partition(int *data, size_t idx_left, size_t idx_right){
  int pivot;
  int i;
  int j;
  pivot = data[idx_left];
  i = idx_left-1;
  j = idx_right+1;

while(1)
{
    do
    {
        i= i+1;
    }while(data[i]<pivot);

    do
    {
        j =j-1;
    }while(data[j]>pivot);

    if (i>=j)
    {
        return j;
    }
    swap(pivot,data[i],data[j]);
}}


static inline void swap(int* data, size_t idx_left, size_t idx_right)
{

  int temp;
  temp = data[idx_right];
  data[idx_right] = data[idx_left];
  data[idx_left] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Point of order, that isn't a segfault. Though I suppose it would probably throw one if you tried to run it anyway.

Comment: The swap function is supposed to work like this: `swap(data, i, j)` instead of `swap(data[i], data[j])`. Your swap involves three indices, `i`, `j` and `pivot`, but you can only swap two items at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the definition of swap:

```
 swap(data, i, j)
```

Comment: And what should i do to make it run?

Comment: What should i put instead of int* data parameter in swap? normally the pivot what i initialiaze or?

Comment: @NewUser2810 -- now that I see your definition of swap I re-wrote the answer

Comment: You want to partition the array. The first item is the pivot. After the loop, you should have a number of items that are smaller than the pivot and then a number of items that are greater than the pivot. To achieve this, you must swap the items at indices `i` and `j` in the loop with `swap(data, i, j)`. After that, you must swap the items at positions `i` and `pivot` in order to make the whole array partitioned. And you must return the position of the pivot, `i` to the calling function, so that it knows where the partitions are.